# How to get local notifications when app enters the background

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone. I am doing Project in that i have struck in the middle because of local notifications concept.In my applications i am sending the request to the server and getting response for every 20 sec by using timer concept but when the application enter the background
how can we get the response from the server for every 20 sec by using local notifications.If anybody knows this concept please help me...

Answer (score 0):

When App on background mode , you receive loacl notification, and you click yes button then

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif
```

this function is call and you get dictionary

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[notif userInfo]);
```

and call the xml in this function.. and  you can get resonance  from your server very easily

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your app doesn't get to execute in the background, and local notifications won't provide you the ability to execute in the background.

([There are exceptions to this, but they come with limitations.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24) If you *really need* to ping a server every 20 sec because you're something like a VoIP app, you can declare that you're a VoIP app and set up a keep-alive handler for doing that ping. However, if you're submitting to the App Store, Apple will require that you're really implementing a VoIP-like app, and not just downloading new RSS feeds in the background or some such.)

What local notifications *are* for is getting the user's attention when your app isn't active. While your app is running, you can schedule a local notification to post a message to the user some time later (sort of like a calendar alarm). If you're using one of the supported background execution modes, you can use a local notification to get the user's attention right now. Either way, your app only gets activated if the user chooses to tap the notification.